# How to disable auto-save message

Tags: emacs

I like the auto-save functionality, but don't like Emacs displaying "Auto-saving...done" every few minutes.

Supposedly, the function that does the auto saving (do-auto-save) has an optional parameter (NO-MESSAGE), but I don't know how to change that parameter without changing the Emacs code (i.e., there is no "customize" functionality to disable or change the message).

What would be the best way to disable the auto-save message without disabling the auto-save functionality?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Emacs usage, with no relation to programming. It has been [re-asked on Emacs Stack Exchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12556/disabling-the-auto-saving-done-message).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do would be to find where `do-auto-save` is being called and change the call, but advising the function is a lazy solution that works:

```
(defadvice do-auto-save (before no-message activate)
  (ad-set-arg 0 t))
```

Comment: Hmm... I tried it but it does not work.  I still get the message "Auto-saving...done."  I am using Emacs 24.3.1.

Comment: I am too, and it works for me.  I follow these steps: 1) open a file; 2) change it without saving; 3) M-x do-auto-save; 4) see "Auto-saving...done" in the `*Messages*` buffer; 5) evaluate the advice; 6) change the flie further; 7) M-x do-auto-save; 8) observe no "Auto-saving done" in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: I don't think that's the right test (the second `do-auto-save` isn't doing anything as not enough text has been entered). The right test is: [1] Execute `(setq auto-save-interval 5) (setq auto-save-timeout  5)`; [2] keep a key pressed (every 5 characters Emacs will auto-save); [3] Execute `(defadvice do-auto-save (before no-message activate) (ad-set-arg 0 t))` [4] keep a key pressed (and now Emacs should not print the auto-save message). I do all this, and Emacs keeps printing "Auto-saving...done." Maybe it's a bug with Emacs 24.3.1?

Comment: This doesn't work, because (as of Emacs 24.4) the `do-auto-save` C function (`Fdo_auto_save`) is called directly from another C function (), bypassing the symbol lookup mechanism that permits advice.